# How to type hint the `$this` property in a trait

Tags: php, traits, type-hinting, phpdoc

I have a trait that that is being used in a class. In that trait, I'd like to be able to type hint which class it is being used.

This trait would most likely be used by that one class only. I only separated its concerns for organization purposes.

```php
class Foo extends Model
{
    use Concerns/HasBar;
}
```

```php
trait HasBar
{
    public function bar()
    {
        $this->... // Type hint $this to Foo
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want type hint all methods and properties from class Foo or only public will be enough?

Comment: @greeflas All methods and properties would be great

Comment: Then you cannot do it with PHPDoc, I think. You can type hint only public members of the class if you add `/* @var Foo $this */` comment inside your `HasBar::bar()` method.

Comment: Too bad but what you suggested would suffice for now. Please post your comment as an answer so that I could mark it as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [var tag](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) inside your `HasBar::bar()` method to type hint public members of the class

```
trait HasBar
{
    public function bar()
    {
        /* @var Foo $this */
        $this->... // Type hint $this to Foo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can put a restriction on a trait to be used exclusively within a specific class.

If you want to implement in such way you may create a sub class instead of using a trait.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. I just want to be able to type hint (not restrict) the `$this` property much like `/** @var \Foo */ public $foo;`